# How to import Raspberry Pi SenseHat data into azure sql server

Tags: sql, raspberry-pi, azure-sql-database, sensors

I have tried every simple and hard python code and I'm still getting errors. Can anyone help me and give me a code how to import Raspberry Pi sensehat data into existing azure sql server.

Here's my .py file :

```
import time
import pymysql.cursors
from sense_hat import SenseHat

sense = SenseHat()

temperature = round(sense.get_temperature(), 1)
pressure = round(sense.get_pressure(), 1)
humidity = round(sense.get_humidity(), 1)

connection = pymysql.connect(host='HOSTNAME',
                             user='USERNAME',
                             password='PASSWORD',
                             db='DATABASE',
                             charset='utf8mb4',
                             cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)

try:
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:

        sql = "INSERT INTO data SET dat_date=%d, dat_time=%d, dat_temperature=%d, dat_pressure=%d, dat_humidity=%d, idx_sensor=%s"
        cursor.execute(sql, (time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),time.strftime("%H:%M:%s"),float(temperature),float(pressure),float(humidity),int(1)))

    connection.commit()
finally:
    connection.close()

sense.show_message("T:" + str(temperature) + " P:" + str(pressure) + " H:" + str(humidity), scroll_speed=0.7
```

Right now I'm getting "`Connection timed out`" error

**Edit:**
I have tried the following command.

```
import time
import pyodbc
from sense_hat import SenseHat

sense = SenseHat()

temperature = round(sense.get_temperature(), 1)
pressure = round(sense.get_pressure(), 1)
humidity = round(sense.get_humidity(), 1)

server = '<server>.database.windows.net'
database = '<database>'
username = '<username>'
password = '{<password>}'   
driver= '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}'

with pyodbc.connect('DRIVER='+driver+';SERVER=tcp:'+server+';PORT=1433;DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password) as conn:
    with conn.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO data SET dat_date=%d, dat_time=%d, dat_temperature=%d, dat_pressure=%d, dat_humidity=%d, idx_sensor=%s")

sense.show_message("T:" + str(temperature) + " P:" + str(pressure) + " H:" + str(humidity), scroll_speed=0.7
```

I'm getting this error: **

```
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

Comment: Have you opened the firewall on the Azure SQL Server? Does your host name end in `.database.windows.net`? Once you sort out connectivity, you need to fix your SQL statement. It shoud be something like `insert into data (dat_date, dat_time) VALUES (%d,%d)`

Answer (score 0):

It has been recommended to use `pyodbc` package as it has better compatibility with Azure SQL database and has direct example from Microsoft.

Run the `pip install pyodbc` command to install the package on your machine.

You also need to install **ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server**. Please visit [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#download-for-windows) to know more about this driver and installation(for Windows OS). The driver is also available for macOS and Linux.

After the package and driver installation, copy and paste the below code in your IDE. Substitute your own values for `<server>, <database>, <username>, and <password>`.

```
import time
import pyodbc
from sense_hat import SenseHat

sense = SenseHat()

temperature = round(sense.get_temperature(), 1)
pressure = round(sense.get_pressure(), 1)
humidity = round(sense.get_humidity(), 1)

server = '<server>.database.windows.net'
database = '<database>'
username = '<username>'
password = '{<password>}'   
driver= '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}'

with pyodbc.connect('DRIVER='+driver+';SERVER=tcp:'+server+';PORT=1433;DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password) as conn:
    with conn.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO data SET dat_date=%d, dat_time=%d, dat_temperature=%d, dat_pressure=%d, dat_humidity=%d, idx_sensor=%s")

sense.show_message("T:" + str(temperature) + " P:" + str(pressure) + " H:" + str(humidity), scroll_speed=0.7
```

If you want to run `SELECT` query, add following code below `cursor.execute` statement in above code to print the fetched data.

```
row = cursor.fetchone()
        while row:
            print (str(row[0]) + " " + str(row[1]))
            row = cursor.fetchone()
```